# How to make a rectangle of 3 colors with Tikzstyle and Tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-styles, backgrounds, tcolorbox, arabic

I've to write a book in arabic, with a background given by an image with stripes in 2 colours in the margin of the page. I include it in the document without any problem with the package bachground. But the labels of my theorems and examples etc,  are written in the margin too, and the result is not very beautiful when it's superimposed on the stripes, because it's color is white. So I want to have the rectangle of the theorem and such in the same color of the background, with the same stripes, blue after white after "yellow" (as if the backgrounds were inversed, the example in background and the image as the document !) . 
I give the original image (to use as background) and an example of document obtained by putting this image as a background. I want to obtain the Tikz rectangle in the same color of the background, a blue sector, after a white sector, after a yellow.
[image] [image]

I give the tex document. Note that the measures given for the boxes are empirical and not very important, because I don't know now the exact position of the stripes. The editor will send it to me later.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}% 

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{R3}}}
\BgThispage

\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
[draw=white, thick, scale=.707, fill=white,% 
    line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, 
number within=section,
number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]{%
enhanced,
left=-5pt,
right=-5pt,
colback=gray!40,
colframe=white,
top=1mm,
bottom=8.5mm,
enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
fontupper=\normalsize,
label={#2},
overlay unbroken and first={%
\node[whitebox]
at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
{\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{2ex}
\mbox{Ex}
\\
\mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
\rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
\end{array}$}}};},
breakable,
before=\par\smallskip\centering,
width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
extrude right by=5pt,
extrude left by=5pt,
#1}%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

The good document.
[image]

**Updated document to include an even/odd command to insert different backgrounds**

It uses the method introduced by Thomas F. Sturm. My aim is to use it only for even pages and, for odd pages, uses the "boxwhite" really white and not in yellow and blue.

I give the result obtained for even/odd.

[image]

[image]

The Code is

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}%

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.388235,0.454902,0.525490}
\definecolor{myYellow}{rgb}{0.643137,0.564706,0.388235}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
{
\backgroundsetup{
%position={0,0},
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{L3}
  }%
}
}%
{
\backgroundsetup{
%position={0,1},
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0)--(-\textwidth-20mm,0);
    \draw[line width=5mm,myBlue](0,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \draw[line width=5mm,myYellow](0.7,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
      }%
}
}%
\BgMaterial}

\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
 [%draw=white,
    thick, scale=.707,%fill=white, fill opacity=0.6,%
    line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle, inner sep=3mm,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
    number within=section,
    number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]%
{%
  enhanced,
  left=-5pt,
  right=-5pt,
  colback=gray!40,
  colframe=white,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=8.5mm,
  enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
  fontupper=\normalsize,
  label={#2},
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \node[whitebox] (B)
      at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
      {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
      \hline
      \rule{0pt}{2ex}
     \mbox{Ex}
      \\
      \mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
      \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
      \end{array}$}}};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw [line width=5mm,myYellow]([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--      ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \draw [line width=5mm,myBlue]([xshift=10.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--   ([xshift=10.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    },
  breakable,
  before=\par\smallskip\centering,
  width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  extrude right by=5pt,
  extrude left by=5pt,
  enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
  #1%
}%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode
\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\newpage
\begin{example}{lab:exam:2}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode
\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

I publish a second update, with the exact dimensions of the page and the images of the background. My question is how to determine exactly the dimensions (found here empirically...) in the underlay (for even pages), for exactly superposing the underlay and the background ?...
Find here the .tex file and it's compilation, together with the images of the background. The arabic word, used in the box, (مثال) means Example.

The tex file

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{changepage}%<----------------- To check even / odd
\strictpagecheck

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm,headheight=14pt,includefoot]{geometry}%

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}


\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.388235,0.454902,0.525490}
\definecolor{myYellow}{rgb}{0.643137,0.564706,0.388235}

    \usepackage{background}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {
    \backgroundsetup{
    %position={0,0},
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    angle=0,
    contents={%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{L}
      }%
    }
    }%
    {
    \backgroundsetup{
    %position={0,1},
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    angle=0,
    contents={%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{R}
          }%
    }
    }%
    \BgMaterial}



\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
[%draw=white, 
thick, scale=.75, %fill=white,% 
line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle,
font=\Large,
left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]


\tikzstyle{yellowbox} =
[fill=myYellow, inner sep=1.5pt, 
thick, scale=.74, draw=myBlue,
line width=1pt, text=black, rectangle,
font=\Large,left]


\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]{%
enhanced,top=0mm,left=-5pt,right=-5pt,enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,enlarge top at break by=0mm, pad at break=2mm,fontupper=\normalsize,
check odd page,% <---------------------------------
overlay unbroken and first={%
 \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
 \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
 \ifoddpage
 \node[yellowbox] (B)
 at ([xshift=12mm,yshift=-.58cm]frame.north east)
    {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{2ex}
    \mbox{\RL{مثال}}
    \\
    \mbox{\Large\thetcbcounter}
    \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
    \end{array}$}}};
 \else    
 \node[whitebox] (B)
 at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-.73cm]frame.north east)
      {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{2ex}
    \mbox{\RL{مثال}}
    \\
    \mbox{\Large\thetcbcounter}
    \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
    \end{array}$}}};
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw [line width=4.7mm,myYellow]([xshift=10mm,yshift=.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--             ([xshift=10mm,yshift=.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \draw [line width=4.7mm,myBlue]([xshift=16mm,yshift=.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--                  ([xshift=16mm,yshift=.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
 \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fi%
    },
breakable,before=\par\smallskip\vspace{-10pt}\centering,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=white,colback=white,
width=\textwidth, borderline north={2pt}{-3pt}{myBlue},borderline south={2pt}{5pt}{myBlue},
label={#2},
#1}




\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\newpage
\begin{example}{lab:exam:2}
\LR{\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

The pdf file obtained :

[image]

[image]

The background images..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems, I misunderstood you question. I thought you would like to have inverted color stripes where the example box runs... I found this a not so bad design idea. Maybe, you (or somebody) can use my answer anyway :-)

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Just a suggestion: perhaps you should delete your answer and give some time to **esdd** to turn his/her comment to a proper answer (as I already suggested him/her); it was his/her idea, and even though you credited him/her in your answer, I think he/she deserves the chance to give the answer. Of course, I insist, this is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As I see now, my answer is a little bit off from the originally intended question. Nevertheless, I find the idea of the inverted colors nice and if you don't mind I keep the answer for a future reader who looks for something like this.*

I had to mock up the missing `R3` picture for the background. So, you will have to adapt the following length settings to your real application. What I have is the following:

[image]

I adapted the `whitebox` a little bit (I removed the `white` color) and added an `underlay` setting to the `tcolorbox`. The `underlay` contains the inverted color stripes.

I used the `underlay`, because it is independent from the `overlay` which will only be set for the first and unbroken page.

The resulting code is:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}%

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,contents={%
  %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{R3}}
  % Mock up, because I do not have the R3 image
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0)--(-\textwidth-20mm,0);
    \draw[line width=5mm,blue!25!gray](0,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \draw[line width=5mm,yellow!25!gray](0.7,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\BgThispage

\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
 [%draw=white,
    thick, scale=.707,% fill=white,%
    line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
    number within=section,
    number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]%
{%
  enhanced,
  left=-5pt,
  right=-5pt,
  colback=gray!40,
  colframe=white,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=8.5mm,
  enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
  fontupper=\normalsize,
  label={#2},
  underlay={%
    \draw [line width=5mm,yellow!25!gray]([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north east);
    \draw [line width=5mm,blue!25!gray]([xshift=10.5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=10.5mm]frame.north east);
  },
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \node[whitebox]
    at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
    {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{2ex}
    \mbox{Ex}
    \\
    \mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
    \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
    \end{array}$}}};},
  breakable,
  before=\par\smallskip\centering,
  width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  extrude right by=5pt,
  extrude left by=5pt,
  enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
  #1%
}%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

As a variant, one could add some semit-transparent white to the `Ex` box. This gives:

[image]

And the code is:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}%

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,contents={%
  %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{R3}}
  % Mock up, because I do not have the R3 image
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0)--(-\textwidth-20mm,0);
    \draw[line width=5mm,blue!25!gray](0,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \draw[line width=5mm,yellow!25!gray](0.7,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\BgThispage

\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
 [%draw=white,
    thick, scale=.707,fill=white, fill opacity=0.6,%
    line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle, inner sep=3mm,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
    number within=section,
    number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]%
{%
  enhanced,
  left=-5pt,
  right=-5pt,
  colback=gray!40,
  colframe=white,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=8.5mm,
  enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
  fontupper=\normalsize,
  label={#2},
  underlay={%
    \draw [line width=5mm,yellow!25!gray]([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north east);
    \draw [line width=5mm,blue!25!gray]([xshift=10.5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=10.5mm]frame.north east);
  },
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \node[whitebox]
    at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
    {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{2ex}
    \mbox{Ex}
    \\
    \mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
    \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
    \end{array}$}}};},
  breakable,
  before=\par\smallskip\centering,
  width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  extrude right by=5pt,
  extrude left by=5pt,
  enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
  #1%
}%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode
\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

As requested by the OP, here is a modification which inverts the colors only below the `whitebox`. Here, the `underlay` is not needed.

[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}%

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.388235,0.454902,0.525490}
\definecolor{myYellow}{rgb}{0.643137,0.564706,0.388235}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,contents={%
  %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{R3}}
  % Mock up, because I do not have the R3 image
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0)--(-\textwidth-20mm,0);
    \draw[line width=5mm,myBlue](0,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \draw[line width=5mm,myYellow](0.7,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\BgThispage

\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
 [%draw=white,
    thick, scale=.707,%fill=white, fill opacity=0.6,%
    line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle, inner sep=3mm,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
    number within=section,
    number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]%
{%
  enhanced,
  left=-5pt,
  right=-5pt,
  colback=gray!40,
  colframe=white,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=8.5mm,
  enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
  fontupper=\normalsize,
  label={#2},
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \node[whitebox] (B)
      at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
      {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
      \hline
      \rule{0pt}{2ex}
      \mbox{Ex}
      \\
      \mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
      \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
      \end{array}$}}};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw [line width=5mm,myYellow]([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \draw [line width=5mm,myBlue]([xshift=10.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--([xshift=10.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    },
  breakable,
  before=\par\smallskip\centering,
  width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  extrude right by=5pt,
  extrude left by=5pt,
  enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
  #1%
}%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode
\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

**Update 2:**

A further request of the OP asks for setting the color switch only for even pages. Therefore, I added the `changepage` package and the `check odd page` key. All changes are marked in the following code, which changes color for even pages and keeps the label box background white for odd pages:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{changepage}%<----------------- To check even / odd
\strictpagecheck

\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}%

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.388235,0.454902,0.525490}
\definecolor{myYellow}{rgb}{0.643137,0.564706,0.388235}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
{
\backgroundsetup{
%position={0,0},
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{L3}
  }%
}
}%
{
\backgroundsetup{
%position={0,1},
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0)--(-\textwidth-20mm,0);
    \draw[line width=5mm,myBlue](0,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \draw[line width=5mm,myYellow](0.7,0)--++(0,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
      }%
}
}%
\BgMaterial}

\tikzstyle{whitebox} =
 [%draw=white,
    thick, scale=.707,%fill=white, fill opacity=0.6,%
    line width=0.3pt, text=black, rectangle, inner sep=3mm,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm]

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
    number within=section,
    number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]%
{%
  enhanced,
  left=-5pt,
  right=-5pt,
  colback=gray!40,
  colframe=white,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=8.5mm,
  enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
  fontupper=\normalsize,
  label={#2},
  check odd page,% <---------------------------------
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \node[whitebox] (B)
      at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
      {\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
      \hline
      \rule{0pt}{2ex}
     \mbox{Ex}
      \\
      \mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
      \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
      \end{array}$}}};
    \ifoddpage\else% <---------------------------------
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw [line width=5mm,myYellow]([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--      ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \draw [line width=5mm,myBlue]([xshift=10.5mm]frame.south east|-B.south)--   ([xshift=10.5mm]frame.north east|-B.north);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fi%
    },
  breakable,
  before=\par\smallskip\centering,
  width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  extrude right by=5pt,
  extrude left by=5pt,
  enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
  #1%
}%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode
\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\newpage
\begin{example}{lab:exam:2}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode
\lipsum[1]}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your method is more beautiful when you inverse the colors. Question : If you have the image what must be the command ? Is there's any method to upload this image on the site that I can watch what must be made ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna You have to find the correct color codes for the two colors (can be done by picking with some drawing program). And you have to play with the length values inside the `underlay` code to match the stripes of the original picture.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Scanning from this web page, the RGB values of the colors should be Gray `0.388235, 0.454902, 0.525490` and Yellow `0.643137, 0.564706, 0.388235`

Comment: Ok I'll do this.. "play with colors and lengths".. immediately when I'll have the exact dimensions from my editor. Your code is excellent and gives good ways of think. Thank you

Comment: Please what means "Gray 0.388235, 0.454902, 0.525490" ? Where do I must enter this dimensions ?

Comment: Other thing, I must background with this image only for the even pages not for all (I must background with another image...on the left margin for the odd pages) , what must the method for this ?... You think that a package like 'ifoddpage' will solve the problem ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Sorry, I was too short. Use `\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.388235,0.454902,0.525490}` and `\definecolor{myYellow}{rgb}{0.643137,0.564706,0.388235}` to create the colors which can be used.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Maybe, you should consult the `background` package for the even/odd question. For the underlay, the `ifoddpage` would be reasonable.

Comment: For the background there's no particular problem for even/odd. For the underlay, I'll test with use of 'ifoddpage' and inform later. Thanks for your help

Comment: +1 You're right. The idea of inverted colors is nice indeed!

Comment: I re-looked to the (nice) result of the underlay option. But it's not very significant if the example has a "large height", and I think that it will be more nice if the height of the underlay is not on all the example, but fixed on small height. For example the height of the Tikz rectangle containing the label. Is there a command for obtaining overlay on a part only of my example ?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Other thing: if I would add the underlay only for the even pages, I tried the command-------

  underlay={

   \@ifoddpage{}{
    \draw [line width=5mm,yellow!25!gray]([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north east);
    \draw [line width=5mm,blue!25!gray]([xshift=10.5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=10.5mm]frame.north east);
  }
  },
----- 
 but this command does nothing, so I obtain the underlay for even and odd page. How can I obtain this underlay only for even pages?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Excuse me but I wasn't explicit in my updated question. How can I obtain a colored box (in my colors yellow and white) for even pages and a white box (not colored) for the odd pages ?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm It was exactly the aim of the problem. Many thanks for this excellent development. I think that when I'll have the really dimension from the editor, I'll play with the dimensions and the scale of the image, and will inform you about the developments. Many thanks another time

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm A last question. The command "line width=5mm" draws a line, so a rectangle, of width 5mm. But what's the "origin" of this rectangle ? What varies and what's fixed in the line-rectangle? More precisely, If I want to increase this width (say to 6mm) this command will increase the width of 1mm from which point of the rectangle ? I haven't found this in the doc of tcolorbox !

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna The `\draw` commands are TikZ commands and `line width` is a TikZ option and documented by the `pgf`/`tikz` package. If this width is increased, the line will get thicker in both directions. You can adapt the `xshift` option to move the line to the intended position.

Comment: I was trying this time and the result is better, but I wanted the exact position of the cursor to put the exact intend. I'll read deeply the doc. Many thanks.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I obtained the images of the background and the exact dimensions of the pages. It's written in the geometry package. I synthetized our discussion in the file uploaded. I've uploaded it's compilation and the two images L.jpg and R.jpg of the background.. I don't know why it's color has changed but the color is what I obtain with my compilation. Any remarks are welcome, essentially about the  distances of the commands..4.7mm...10mm..16mm what I obtain empirically and not exactly... Can you tell me about the method for finding this measures, please. With my many thanks for all...

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Since the background images seem to be external graphics, the empiric way to determine the distances by testing seems to be the best one.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks for your answer and many thanks another time for this macro. I'm sure that the institute has of course the exact dimensions, and so one can do this exactly if.. I'll do this empirically and I hope that it'll be beautiful..

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in my comment, you can use `\node[whitebox,draw=none,fill=none]...` or you can change the `draw=white` and `fill=white` options of the `whitebox` style to `draw=none` and `fill=none`.

Note, that the up to date syntax for setting styles is

```
\tikzset{whitebox/.style={...}}
```

Additionally the option `thick` will be overwritten by the later option `line width=0.3pt`.

So I suggest to use

```
\tikzset{
  whitebox/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw=none, fill=none,
    scale=.707, line width=.3pt,
    text=black, font=\Large, left,
    minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm
  }
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[total={165mm,235mm},includefoot,includehead,headheight=14pt,centering,twoside]{geometry}% 

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{R3}}}
\BgThispage

\tikzset{
  whitebox/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw=none, fill=none,
    scale=.707, line width=.3pt,
    text=black, font=\Large, left,
    minimum height=.5cm, minimum width=1.9cm
  }
}

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, 
number within=section,
number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[2][]{%
enhanced,
left=-5pt,
right=-5pt,
colback=gray!40,
colframe=white,
top=1mm,
bottom=8.5mm,
enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
fontupper=\normalsize,
label={#2},
overlay unbroken and first={%
\node[whitebox]
at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.9cm]frame.north east)
{\strut\RL{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{2ex}
\mbox{Ex}
\\
\mbox{\large\thetcbcounter}
\rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
\end{array}$}}};},
breakable,
before=\par\smallskip\centering,
width=\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
extrude right by=5pt,
extrude left by=5pt,
#1}%

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{green}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{example}{lab:exam:1}
\LR{The text of the example (labeled here Ex) is usually in arabic, in RightToLeft mode}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```